# How to convert sshfs command to fstab entry?

Tags: command-line, mount, fstab

From another SO [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10947/how-to-auto-mount-my-external-hard-drive), I understand I should create an entry in `fstab` to permanently mount an access to a virtual machine.

I am not Linux expert. The magic command which allows me to perform this from a terminal is:

```
sudo sshfs -o idmap=user -o allow_other -o nonempty jverstrynge@devjverstrynge:/home/httpd /home/jverstrynge/httpd
```

When I check the above SO question, I see an entry looking like this:

```
/media/mybook/laptop_backup /export/laptop_backup none bind 0 0
```

Can someone explain how to transform the CLI command into an entry in `fstab`?

Comment: Checkout the entry in http://askubuntu.com/a/334171/158442

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can use this syntax:

```
sshfs#USER@HOST:REMOTE_PATH LOCAL_PATH fuse defaults,_netdev,allow_other 0 0
```

E.g.

```
sshfs#jverstrynge@devjverstrynge:/home/httpd /home/jverstrynge/httpd fuse defaults,_netdev,allow_other 0 0
```

But this works only if you use ssh keys for authentication.

Comment: If you intend to use the allow_other mount option like the answer above suggests, be aware that the Linux kernel has an unresolved security bug that affects FUSE. See https://github.com/libfuse/libfuse/issues/15

Comment: Similar to the answer below regarding autofs, the options field of fstab (defaults,allow_other above) may include any option in ssh_config like: IdentityFile=some_file, etc.  Perhaps choosing only aes256 cypher since 128 is default or setting up a PKI provider for smartcards (btw for US federal users you can set up standard Id smartcards, just don't forget revocation.)  Finally two notes (untested) considere /etc/ssh/sshd_config and the "delay_connect" option to speed up boot.

Comment: This works with root's ssh configuration. Is there a way to make it use my user's? I'd like it to use my host configuration without having to copy it over.

Comment: @Paul You can specify a custom SSH command. Building on the posted example: 

`sshfs#jverstrynge@devjverstrynge:/home/httpd /home/jverstrynge/httpd fuse defaults,_netdev,allow_other,ssh_command=ssh\040-F\040/home/jverstrynge/.ssh/config 0 0`

 I had to format it like this to get it to recognize the hostname from the config file:  

`jverstrynge@devjverstrynge:/home/httpd /home/jverstrynge/httpd fuse.sshfs defaults,_netdev,allow_other,ssh_command=ssh\040-F\040/home/jverstrynge/.ssh/config 0 0`

Note that the `\040` in both examples is an octal escape sequence for the space character.

Comment: The sshfs#USER@HOST syntax was deprecated in latest FUSE implementations. Now it's : user@a.b.c.d:/ /mnt/XSI/srvs/e.f.g.h fuse.sshfs + options

Answer (score 12):

[From this source](https://superuser.com/questions/669287/automount-sshfs-using-fstab-without-mount-a)

this works for non systemd,see article for other config (Fedora, Arch, openSuse,...)

```
USERNAME@HOSTNAME_OR_IP:/REMOTE/DIRECTORY  /LOCAL/MOUNTPOINT  fuse.sshfs _netdev,user,idmap=user,transform_symlinks,identityfile=/home/USERNAME/.ssh/id_rsa,allow_other,default_permissions,uid=USER_ID_N,gid=USER_GID_N 0 0
```

a systemd distro (Arch, Fedora, OpenSUSE,...), the suitable instruction is:

```
USERNAME@HOSTNAME_OR_IP:/REMOTE/DIRECTORY  /LOCAL/MOUNTPOINT  fuse.sshfs x-systemd.automount,_netdev,user,idmap=user,transform_symlinks,identityfile=/home/USERNAME/.ssh/id_rsa,allow_other,default_permissions,uid=USER_ID_N,gid=USER_GID_N 0 0
```

Comment: USERNAME occurs twice.  In the first case it is obviously remote - in the second (identity file) it is local I guess.

Comment: yes correct, first is remote user, second is the local path

Comment: Works fine in Ubuntu. I only had to remove the uid and gid part. Accessing files in my file manager without root is possible which is nice.

Comment: @matt3o note that under Ubuntu: uid=1000,gid=1000

Comment: Doesn't work for me. When I execute `mount -a` after having written all of that, the command just hangs indefinitely, and there is no logs in `journalctl` about that.

Comment: adding `,sec=ntlmssp` works for mine for Pop!_OS/Ubuntu 22.04

Answer (score 7):

Try `autofs`

create `auto.master`:

```
/mount /etc/auto.sshfs        uid=1000,gid=1000,--timeout=30,--ghost
```

create `auto.sshfs` - `moviefolder`:

```
fstype=fuse,rw,allow_other,noatime,port=54321,IdentityFile=/root/.ssh/id_rsa :sshfs\#root@10.70.70.12\:/var/www/html/moviefolder
```

You need to have ssh keys for this to work.