# Mounting a remote directory at start up

Tags: server, vlc, sshfs

I am new to servers and getting confused I think.
I have created a server using ubuntu server.
I can now see the directories I want on my home machine which is running linux 
I have been trying different things to make it work but I think this is what made it work!

```
apt-get sshfs; 
mkdir ~/jehu;
sshfs phil@192.168.1.126:/home/phil /home/phil/jehu
```

once this is up and running I can then access the files on the server from Eg VLC using the `file:///home/phil/jehu` link

just getting confused...have I muddled up the commands?
is this the best way to do this?

I have just started my server again, and I can't now access the files using `file:///home/phil/jehu` link
what I want is something that will link this up on boot, not that I have to do manually

any help would be appreciated
thanks

dykesy61

Comment: Maybe this translated webpage can help you a little: https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=de&tl=en&u=https%3A%2F%2Fwiki.ubuntuusers.de%2FFUSE%2Fsshfs%2F%23Benutzung It describes the settings for `User mapping`, `Include symlinks`, `Automount`, `At system start`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert sshfs command to fstab entry?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/710149/how-to-convert-sshfs-command-to-fstab-entry)

Answer (score 1):

You can [add information to /etc/fstab](https://askubuntu.com/questions/710149/how-to-convert-sshfs-command-to-fstab-entry) to make this work. But if you need to supply a password to make the remote connection then that is not an option.  You can [create a passwordless key](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-setup-passwordless-ssh-login/) to use for ssh, but that comes with security implications and I would not recommend it.  Overally, I would suggest you look into a different protocol like NFS for LAN or DAV for a connection across the internet.

Comment: thanks - I have found some info about nfs sharing....once I have mounted the server directory on the client machine, how do I ensure it mounts each time ie that I don't have to do this again and again?  Thanks

Comment: Again, you make the entry in /etc/fstab.  Have a look at "man fstab" and google for examples.  There's plenty and many knobs to tweak (if you want).  The link I already gave you answers both your initial and your follow-up question.